# Automation Anywhere - the scheduled task can't run on the runner

Tags: automationanywhere

I scheduled a task to run in the control room but it couldn't run unless I log on to the runner machine. Please let me know how I fix this. I get this message

> AAE was unable to unlock or logon onto the machine RUNNERMACHINE to run the task. Check the Login Settings (under Tools->Options) in AAE Client on RUNNERMACHINE. Refer the AAE Client’s help documentation on Auto - Login for more details

Comment: When logged into the client, have you tried putting in the autologin settings as the message suggest?

Comment: yes, sometimes it ran ok sometimes wasn't able to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure a couple of things - make sure you have Auto Login enabled in the Options of the AA Client under Login Settings. Also make sure your credentials there are correct. If there is a legal disclaimer, you'll need to use that bypass checkbox.

If you use remote desktop to access your bot runners, you may need to run a batch file to forcibly log yourself off so the Control Room can connect through its RDP to the bot runner.

`for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`

Might look something like that.

Comment: We also use a batch file with the same code as above on the odd few VMs we have issues with. I'll add you should run this batch file as administrator (Right click - run as admin)

Comment: Also, with the legal disclaimer and the byapss checkbox, if you have any additional screens upon logging in, for example we had a summary screen of any last login\failed logins, you will need to change group policy so they don't show otherwise the bot will not be able to auto login